# Slack Bolt, Moving command callback into another file

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

I am learning to create a Slack app. I have created an app and it works, however the main `app.ts` file is quite bloated. I want to go from having code that looks like this

```js
slackApp.command('command', async ({ack,command,response}) = {
 // Do all of the things here 
 // and here
 // and here
})
```

to something like this

```js
import { MyFunctionHere } from './commands.ts'

slackApp.command('command', async MyFunctionHere)
```

with another typescript file called something like commands.ts with

```js
export MyFunctionHere = () => {
 // Do all of the things here 
 // and here
 // and here
}
```

Though I am not sure how to go about moving the anonymous function from the first example into a separate file like the second example.

Comment: The `async` keyword is part of the function definition. Not part of the argument syntax. So it should be `slackApp.command('command', MyFunctionHere)` and `export MyFunctionHere = async () => { ...`

Comment: @slebetman when I tried `export MyFunctionHere = async ({ack,command,response}) => { ... }` the exported function complained about the `ack,command,response` deconstruction from the slack bolt `slackApp.command()` listener and I am not sure how to deal with that.

Comment: You can just simply not deconstruct it. Just do `MyFunctionHere = async (x) { ...` and then access those properties the **normal** way: `x.ack`, `x.command` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this.

The resolution I used was to set the type of the `const MyFunctionHere` to `Middleware<SlackCommandMiddlewareArgs>` resulting in no compilation errors from TypeScript.

The following is my example code:

**app.ts**

```js
import { MyFunctionHere } from './commands.ts'

slackApp.command('command', async MyFunctionHere)
```

**command.ts**

```js
const MyFunctionHere: Middleware<SlackCommandMiddlewareArgs> = async ({ ack,command,response }) => {

await ack()

}

export = { MyFunctionHere }
```

Thanks for the comments, I hope this is able to help someone else.